# Writing a File in Android

Tags: java, android, string, file

First of all, I'm sorry if exists a similar post but I was not able to understand.

I'm trying to write a file in android and I got the following code:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file.txt";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos;
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("Angles", "FileNotFoundException");
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("Angles", "IOException");
}
```

I don't get any exception so I suppose it works but I'm not able to find the hello_file.txt file inside the device.

I'm running on Galaxy Nexus; no sd.

Comment: All the permissions you need have been declared? Also, you're probably writing to the app's /data/ folder.

Comment: It's that enough?: android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS

Comment: It looks like it might be a file permission issue - to quote the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) `File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).`

Comment: make sure this permission is in the manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

which should allow you to write in:
/sdcard/Android/data/[package_name]/cache

Comment: Try `android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` too. Also specify an actual file path. Just writing may have made it local to the app, which is the `/data/` folder.

Comment: I did a search everywhere on the device and isn't any hello_file.txt file.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/hello_file.txt contains a path separator

Comment: I tried with String FILENAME = "/data/hello_file.txt"; but it seems I can't specify the path in this way. How should I specify it?

Comment: I have tried this time to write the path of the context.
String path = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
  Log.d("Angles", path );

Comment: And it's /data/data/com.Aikon.angles/files. I'm not able to see that path on the device. I don't understand.

Comment: Applications' private directoires are by default restricted from access by other entities, including you.  On an emulator or device where ADBD runs as root you can access these with DDMS, otherwise if the apk is debuggable you can use the run-as tool and adb shell commands - failing that, you'll have to make the app itself mark the file world readable or copy it out to the external storage.

Comment: check out this link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStratton . Now, all get sense. I didn't get MODE_PRIVATE. I didn't think that I wasn't able to open it from windows explorer.
THX!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a file in sdcard, you need to use

```
File f =  new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"myfile.txt")
```